# How do I set up cosmosdb emulator locally from powershell script

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

I am doing some testing on my cosmos db and I would like to use Cosmos Db emulator to be set up locally using scripts. I would like to use PowerShell scripts to create Db , containers , populate test data using PowerShell in cosmos db emulator but I couldn't find any documentation online. Can someone direct me or help me in doing this. Till now I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-command-line-parameters#:%7E:text=Install%20the%20latest%20version%20of,Azure.) documentation which allows me to start CosmosDb emulator using PowerShell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to use PowerShell scripts to create Db , containers ,
> populate test data using PowerShell in cosmos db emulator but I
> couldn't find any documentation online.

The PowerShell module ([`Az.Cosmos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/?view=azps-5.8.0)) provided by Microsoft focuses only on the Cosmos DB accounts in the cloud. As of version 5.8.0, it does not have a support for Cosmos DB emulator.

Luckily there's a community solution available that you can use: https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB.

To create a context for emulator account, this is what you will have to do:

```
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Emulator -Database 'MyDatabase'
```

Once you have the context, you should be able to create databases and containers. For example:

```
New-CosmosDbDatabase -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'MyDatabase' -OfferThroughput 1200

New-CosmosDbCollection -Context $cosmosDbContext -Id 'MyNewCollection' -PartitionKey 'id' -OfferThroughput 50000
```

This project was last updated 6 months ago so I am not sure if it has all the features you're looking for.

Other idea would be to make use of Cosmos DB .Net SDK and use that in PowerShell scripts of your own.

**UPDATE**

This is what I did:

1. I opened the PowerShell console in `Admin` mode.
2. I installed `Cosmos` module using `Install-Module -Name CosmosDB`. I got an error initially (something about module not found) which I fixed by setting the TLS command to 1.2 using `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`.
3. Then I started the emulator using your commands.
4. After that I created the context using `$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Emulator`.
5. After that I listed the databases in my Cosmos emulator account and was able to successfully do so.

[image]

Comment: this is what i get in on running the cosmosdbcontext command:
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Emulator -Database 'testdatabase'
"New-CosmosDbContext: The term 'New-CosmosDbContext' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: i also did an import module and start cosmosdb before running the above command, but it does nt seems to be working
Import-Module "$env:ProgramFiles\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\PSModules\Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Emulator"
Start-CosmosDbEmulator

Comment: I just tried to perform these steps and was able to complete them successfully. No errors in executing `New-CosmosDbContext` command.

Comment: can you please elaborate the steps.. i downloaded cosmos db emulator locally, imported the module and start the emulator with powershell command.. and then ran the new-cosmosDbContext command.. any thing i am missing?

Comment: Let me edit my answer and provide details.

Comment: In which directory did you run the context?

Comment: Ran the PS Console in Admin mode so it was in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: After that I listed the databases in my Cosmos emulator account and was able to successfully do so. i dont see this line in powershell.. you listed the database using pws command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231913/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-zzzsharepoint).